# Union of pairwise disjoint of prefect sets is still prefect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Recall that a set $A\subset\Bbb R$ perfect set provided it is closed and has no isolated point. \
Now, for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, choose a perfect set $P_n\subset(n,n+1).$ Put, $P:=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} P_n.$ Notcie that all $P_n$'s are pairwise disoint sets. So, $P$ will not have an isolated point. Notice that $\{P_n\colon n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a locally finite in $\Bbb R$, a collection $\mathcal A$ of subset of $\Bbb R$ is said to be locally finite in $\Bbb R$ if every point of $\Bbb R$ has a neighborhood that intersects only finitly many elements of $\mathcal A.$ Recall that $\mathcal A$ is locally finite then $$\overline{\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}}A=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}\overline{A}$$
So, this will show that $P$ is closed. So, $P$ is a perfect set.
Maybe it is easy but I made it complicated. Any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a big theorem and that is not necessary. Let $(x_i)$ be  sequence in $P$ converging to $x$. Choose $n$ such that $|x| <n$. The $|x_i| <n+1$ for $n$ sufficiently large, say, for $n \geq N$, so $(x_N,x_{N+1},...)$ is a sequence in $\bigcup_{|i|\leq n+1} P_i$ and $\bigcup_{|i|\leq n+1} P_i$ is closed. Hence, $x \in \bigcup_{|i|\leq n+1} P_i \subset P$.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, this is better from did. Was my explanation right ?

Comment: Yes, yours was also right. @Gob